# Mass contribution during the LHB

Tags: earth-history, meteorite

How much mass (either absolute or relative to the Earth) was [estimate to have been] added to the Earth during the Late Heavy Bombardment?

Comment: Graphs [Fig. 1](http://www.univie.ac.at/geochemistry/koeberl/publikation_list/243-LHB-Kuiper-Belt-objects-EMP2004.pdf) and [Fig. 6](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d662/489cff0cdf629de1b4b9c0502d4022a5b46a.pdf) show LHB accretion rate spikes for the Moon. I guess the rates for the Earth could be inferred from this.

Comment: I remember seeing a paper recently that did some mass balance calculations. Can't remember which one. I would start with a [Google Scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_ylo=2016&q=late+veneer+earth) on the topic and try to find some estimates.